# How do you use chartkick with viewcomponent?

Tags: chartkick, view-components

When rendering chartkick charts in [view_component](https://viewcomponent.org) and you have multiple charts in one page, the only one chart ends up getting rendered.

The issue is the same or similar to [this one](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/pull/192).

How do you render chartkick charts with view component?

Answer (score 0):

In a parent component class like `ApplicationComponent`, define what you'll use as the chart's id:

```rb
  def chartkick_chart_id
    self.class.name.underscore.dasherize.gsub("/", "--")
  end
```

Then, override `chartkick_chart` to set the `id` of the chart so that the [default setting of chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/blob/bcae3e137a641f2a95e79a48007c648a4d2ef3d4/lib/chartkick/helper.rb#L45) does not kick in.

```rb
  alias_method :orig_chartkick_chart, :chartkick_chart

  def chartkick_chart(klass, data_source, **options)
    opts = options.merge(id: chartkick_chart_id)
    orig_chartkick_chart klass, data_source, **opts
  end
```

This will work as long as you render one type of the same chart page page. If you render two charts in the same page (I don't see why you would), add some randomizing string to the ID.